# Unregister Nav Menu with fallback?

Tags: functions, menus, child-theme

I am trying to create a child theme so theme updates are much easier.  I want to remove the parent theme menus and add my own.  I know I can modify the header.php file (where these menus exist) and edit the wp_nav_menus directly, but I'm trying to avoid using as many theme files as possible, so I'm trying to accomplish this in my functions.php file.

Using [unregister_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_nav_menu) I am able to remove the menu from the parent theme location as such:

```
function RR_remove_parent_theme_menus()     {
    unregister_nav_menu( 'top-menu' );
    unregister_nav_menu( 'header-menu' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'RR_remove_parent_theme_menus', 20 );
```

This works great for "top-menu" but "header-menu" is coded in the parent theme with a custom fallback.  Is there any way to override a custom (or a default) menu fallback using unregister_nav_menu or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter `'wp_nav_menu_args'`, set an invalid `theme_location` and the magic function `__return_false` as fallback:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'override_parent_args' );

function override_parent_args( $args )
{
    if ( 'header-menu' === $args['theme_location'] )
    {
        $args['fallback_cb']    = '__return_false';
        $args['theme_location'] = 'ticky_tacky';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: How would I filter it to be /completely/ gone?  I don't want any remnants of the container or the contents in there.

Comment: @RodeoRamsey Maybe an invalid `theme_location` with `__return_false` as `fallback_cb`?