# Remove nav menu or menu item

Tags: menus

I try to remove a nav menu programmatically but I didn't find the way to do it. I knwo how to create it but I don't know how to delete it...
I've got the menu name and I wan't to delete it like in wp admin panel but programmatically.

Or I want to delete all the menu item inside it.

Comment: Just delete it from admin.

Comment: programmatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unregister Nav Menu with fallback?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97851/unregister-nav-menu-with-fallback)

Comment: I just try but it's not working in my case. In fact I want to completely delete the nav menu or item inside the nav menu then repopulate it... What wordpress do when you click on delete menu?

Answer (score 6):

Finally the answer is simple:

```
$menu_name   = 'your menu';//name,id,slug
wp_delete_nav_menu($menu_name);
```

Comment: This answers the nav menu - But what about menu item?

Comment: In fact, this is a good start for deleting a menu and its items since WordPress handles this directly.

Answer (score 0):

As the question was "Remove nav menu or menu item -programmatically-?"

Since WordPress 3.0, there is native dedicated function to do so: [wp_delete_nav_menu()](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L265). It deletes the menu nav and all related menu items, no need to use wp_delete_post anymore.

So, depending on the context:

- A. in pure code in php, use `wp_delete_nav_menu()`;
- B. in WP Cli, there is the [`wp menu delete`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/menu/delete/) command, which call wp_delete_nav_menu;

So to conclude, in both cases, all menu items and the menu will be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question but I just found the solution for myself. In order to delete all (or some) menu items from a menu you could first get the menu items and then use `wp_delete_post()`.

From: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_nav_menu/ (line 271)

```
$menu_objects = get_objects_in_term( $menu->term_id, 'nav_menu' );
if ( ! empty( $menu_objects ) ) {
    foreach ( $menu_objects as $item ) {
        wp_delete_post( $item );
    }
}
```